# How send a static object in to event for `PropertyChanged`

Tags: wpf, mvvm, user-controls, static, dependency-properties

I have a project by MVVM pattern. also I have a User Control in it. This user Control has a static DependencyProperty

```
public partial class RadarView : INotifyPropertyChanged
{


public static DispatcherTimer Timer { get; set; }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty RequestTypeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("RequestType", typeof(RadarRequestType), typeof(RadarView), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new RadarRequestType(), RequestTypeChanged));

        public RadarRequestType RequestType
        {
            get
            {
                return
                    (RadarRequestType)GetValue(RequestTypeProperty);
            }
            set { SetValue(RequestTypeProperty, value); }
        }

        public static void RequestTypeChanged(DependencyObject dobject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
        var radar = (RadarView)dobject;

            if (Timer == null)
                Timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1) };

            Timer.Tick += DispatcherTimerTick;

            Timer.Start();

        }

        private static void DispatcherTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StartText = DateTime.Now.Second.ToString();

            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("StartText"));
        }

        public static event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

}
```

My problem is in DispatcherTimerTick , because this in it event is same my user Control and it is not static. Message of this build error is : Keyword 'this' is not valid in a static property, static method, or static field initializer

In fact I need to send (RadarView)dobject to DispatcherTimerTick event. How can do I?

Comment: Why do you need the timer to be static ?

Comment: @NicolasRepiquet: Because RequestTypeChanged is static and It must be static

Comment: Of course `RequestTypeChanged` as to be static. But you got a reference to `RadarView` in it, so nothing prevent you to do something like `radar.Timer`. Sharing the same timer across all of your `RadarView` instances doesn't sounds good.

Comment: @NicolasRepiquet: My problem was solved. My use of the `Timer` was wrong. I needed to `radar.Timer`. Thanks for your commenting. Please enter this comment in answer for mark as answer.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved. My use of the `Timer` was wrong. I needed to `radar.Timer`.